# SQL Update All rows NO WHERE statement VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, rows

I need to update all rows in multiple columns at the same time. Basically full data table. The data table format is prebuilt. I am new to ADO and only have a couple of weeks with it. 
Here is a problem I can update each row individually but can't update all. Everywhere I looked from MS to Forums they keep referring to "WHERE". As one main column referencing others. This is NOT what I need. All I need is table to be updated in the database when APP is closed or crashed and Loaded when APP is open.

I have tried pretty much everything so far from actual SQL to SQL commands. But column keeps updating as full with single value since I have no reference WHERE and when saving I am referencing the index on the row... If I try to use for statement as I use for the load it throws an error obviously because it just dumps the full data with "ExecuteNonQuery". I would think I need to load adapter with data and then load it with the database but I am getting errors with it as well....

```
VB.net Load From Database

    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim sql As String = "Select * FROM Table1"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Data") ' Data tags data

    'Count Rows In data Table
    Dim commandRowCount As New SqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM " + "dbo.Table1", connection)
    Dim countStart As Long = System.Convert.ToInt32(commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar())
    TextBox1.Text = countStart


    For x = 0 To countStart - 1
        If x = 0 Then
            DataG.Rows.Add(1)
        ElseIf x < countStart - 1 Then
            DataG.Rows.Add(x)
        End If
        DataG.Rows(x).Cells("Column1").Value = ds.Tables("Data").Rows(x).Item("Column1")
        DataG.Rows(x).Cells("Column2").Value = ds.Tables("Data").Rows(x).Item("Column2")
        DataG.Rows(x).Cells("Column3").Value = ds.Tables("Data").Rows(x).Item("Column3")
    Next

    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Save Data - ISSUE:

```
Dim connetionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connetionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Update Table1 SET Column1 = @Column1", con)
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()


    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Column1", DataG.Item("Column1", rowIndex:=0).Value))


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()'''
```

I would assume this MS example should work for what I need but it keeps throwing Error Column1 NOT supplied for whatever reason. However, a value in the cell is present and there are no empty rows. So I am super confused why it thinks value doesn't exist. However, if I refer to column one as "DataG.Rows(1).Cells("Column1").Value" it works.... which means I need to define Table somewhere but I have no idea where

```
 Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
    connection.Open()
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * FROM Table1 ", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Column1")
    adapter.SelectCommand = command
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) " & "VALUES (@Column1)", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, "Column1")
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    adapter.InsertCommand = command
    command = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Table1 Set Column1 = @Column1", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, "Column1")
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim parameter As SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, "Column1")
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
    adapter.UpdateCommand = command
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    command = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = @Column1", connection)
    parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.NChar, 50, "Column1")
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
    adapter.DeleteCommand = command
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I believe I either need to load data adapter with my table or apply FOR statement.
Or possibly both fill data adapter with all the rows and send it to the database for an update.

Comment: What are you trying to update all your table values to?

Comment: Hi, inputs from the APP in DataTable. Values are generated in DataTable thru APP. This data table needs to be saved when APP is closed and Loaded When APP is open. However, DataTable can be empty.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with strongly typed datasets - are you averse to using them?

Comment: Using a SELECT query with an ExecuteNonQuery doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, are we talking about stored procedures? I am new... I can use whatever works. I tried stored procedures and above but both produced the same effect

Comment: LarsTech - Those were just references  I found my code is above

Answer (score 0):

The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

ADO has 3 classes that I am using.

- DataTable - an in memory representation of the result of a Select
  statement. Here I used the Load Method to fill it with data.
- SQLConnection - The connection string is passed to the constructor.
- SQLCommand - The Sql statement and the connection are passed to the
  constructor. Additions to the Parameters collection are made with the
  .Add(parameterName, datatype, size) followed by .Value to set the
  value of the parameter.

Open the connection at the last possible moment. It will be closed as soon as possible with the `End Using`

I am not sure what the final block of your code is supposed to do.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode1()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * FROM Table1", connection)
            connection.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using 'Close and dispose command
    End Using 'Close and dispose connection
    'I am assuming that DataG is the name of a DataGridView on you form
    DataG.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub OPCode2()
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Update Table1 SET Column1 = @Column1", con)
            'The item property references a cell in the grid Item(columnIndex As Integer, rowIndex As Integer)
            'So this sets the value to the first column (index 0) of the first row (index 0)
            'Since the size of the field is 50, it wouldn't make any sense for it to be NChar.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = DataG.Item(0, 0).Value
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
You want to make changes to the DataGridView and have these changes made to the database. Yes? No need to prebuild anything just as long as the table exists in the database.

The DataGridView is filled from the `DataTable` which is loaded from the database. Once the grids `.DataSource` property is set to the `DataTable` it is bound. Changes made to the data in the UI are reflected in the `DataTable`. You can add update or delete as long as you have included the Primary Key in the Select statement.

When you get ready to update the database you would click the Update button. The `DataTable` has keep track of any changes to the grid. The DataAdapter will send these changes to the database with the Update method. We must recreate the Select command so the adapter can build the Insert, Update, and Delete statements associated with the Select. (see `SqlCommandBuilder`). `Open` the connection, call `Update()` and finally call `.AcceptChanges()` on the `DataTable`. That final step allows you to make more changes and update again without repeating the first updates.

Note: The DataTable is now a class level variable, available to both procecures.

```
Private dt As New DataTable

Private Sub UpdateDataAdapter_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.BuildersConnectio)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Products", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.BuildersConnectio)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * From Products", cn)
        Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        cn.Open()
        adapter.Update(dt)
        dt.AcceptChanges()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I need all rows and cells to be updated. OPCode2 does only for specified cell/row and if I pass it thru the loop  I will get an Error" Column something" In other words, I can't loop by adding a parameter.

Comment: Please see EDIT to my answer. Your intention was not initially clear to me.

Comment: I am getting "Value cannot be null." error at" adapter.Update(dt)". Unfortunately, I don't have KEY binding that identifies the row and my guess this is my main problem. All examples have this. Hence then I asked if there is a way to update without "WHERE" statement based on "ROW COUNT" property instead. APP VS DATABASE row count and update solely on APP count. I am not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Does your table in the database have a Primary Key?

Comment: Are any of the fields in the database marked not null?

Comment: Hi, my table does NOT have a primary key and all accepted as the NULL. Mainly because of all Columns can be NULL for Example: IF APP's DataTable is completely empty it will refer to DataBase as Empty. Perhaps SQL is NOT something I need because typically DataBase is the Key drive in App. In my case its opposite App Drives DataBase.

Comment: Should I add a primary KEY and hide it in data table? Looks Like the only solution

Comment: First let's get some vocabulary straight. Sql Server hosts databases. Database contain all sorts of things like diagrams, stored procedures, views, and Tables. It would make no sense to connect to an Empty Database. Yes, I would most certainly add a Primary Key to the database Table.

Comment: Thanks Mary, It looks like XML can work for me in this case instead. However, I am still curious with SQL how would I cycle thru SQL primary Values? Would I need to set "As longest primary key > 0"  value or I be able to use the method you provided above?

Comment: There is no need to loop through rows when using the .Update method. The DataTable keeps track of any changes made in the DataGridView that it is bound to. When you call Update the rows that are changed are provided to the adapapter by the DataTable and the changes sent to the database. This is fast but only works if the Select includes a primary key and does not use joins.

Comment: Somehow I am still getting value as a null error, I have set the primary key to column one and modified stored procedure to Column1=@Column1